# slow loading using initWithContentsOfUrl

Tags: lazy-loading, nsdata, initwithcontentsofurl

I have a web service and I make HTTP calls to it from cocoa using this line of code:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:url options: NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

Sometimes is it take 10 seconds, sometimes 30 seconds to load the picture from this URL.
I tried loading this URL from a normal browser and it takes 1-2 seconds.
I'm doing lazy loading and the problem is the time it takes to load the contents of this URL vs a normal browser. Both tests were done from the same network.

Download.m

```
NSError *error;

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.photoRecord.URL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:imageData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&myError];
NSMutableDictionary *pictureInfo = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *picture;
picture = [pictureInfo valueForKey:@"Picture"];
NSData *base64Data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64Encoding:picture];
if (base64Data) {
      UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:base64Data];
      self.photoRecord.image = downloadedImage;
}
[(NSObject *)self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageDownloaderDidFinish:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Then on the main thread PictureController.m:

```
-(void) loadScrollViewWithPage:(NSUInteger)page{
    ....
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:page inSection:0];
    [self startOperationsForPhotoRecord:aRecord atIndexPath:myIndexPath];
}

- (void)startOperationsForPhotoRecord:(PictureRecord *)record atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Download *imageD = [[Download alloc] initWithPhotoRecord:record atIndexPath:indexPath delegate:self];
    [self.pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress setObject:imageD forKey:indexPath];
    [self.pendingOperations.downloadQueue addOperation:imageD];
}
```

Then I have the delegate method to update the UIImageView when the download is done which is working just fine.

The size of the content being loaded is around 400kb.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: This one is for my test server. It's a picture in JSON format from my web service: http://websrveventsapp.cloudapp.net/GetPictures.svc/getPictures/?Event=SociBasePortugues&picid=34

Comment: Can you share your code editing your post?